# How to execuete windows workflow from commandline

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I need to execute workflow from command line that is already created using UI.

Already I have tried to invoke workflow by creating workflow instance.
the code shown below which is i was tried

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("Workflow1.xml");

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Workflow completion..");

        WorkflowRuntime runtime = new WorkflowRuntime();

        WorkflowInstance instance = runtime.CreateWorkflow(reader);

        instance.Start();
```

but it shows the error message "xml tag is not framed well".
I have fully copied the workflow xaml content and pasted in Workflow1.xml file.

is there any other possibilities to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Windows Workflow 4, but you are trying to use the Windows Workflow 3 runtime to execute the workflow. I've got a white paper [[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx)] on WF 4 that might be useful, but here's a snippet from that article that might be helpful. It uses the workflowInvoker class  to execute the workflow. You can also use WorkflowApplication if you have long running workflows that need bookmarking capabilities.

```
Activity mathWF;

using (Stream mathXaml = File.OpenRead("Math.xaml"))
{
    mathWF = ActivityXamlServices.Load(mathXaml);
}

var outputs = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(mathWF,
    new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "operand1", 5 },
    { "operand2", 10 },
    { "operation", "add" } });

Assert.AreEqual<int>(15, (int)outputs["result"], "Incorrect result returned");
```

[Developer's Introduction to Windows Workflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Matt Milner